# What can I photograph beautifully during or just after a rainstorm?

Tags: inspiration, rain

What can I photograph beautifully during a storm, when it is raining, or just after it rains?

I would like to get some subject ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Shoot details such as leaves, rocks, plants, etc with rain on them.
- Shoot skys with the great clouds that thunderstorms usually have.
- Use the cloudy sky as a giant free diffuser and take soft portrait shots.
- If you are in an urban setting shoot people running around with umbrellas and through large puddles.
- Frame the image to remove the sky if it is uninteresting or dull
- Use filters to warm the images
- Switch your WB to a different setting to get a warmer or cooler image
- Look for puddles or things to capture reflections

Comment: +1 for suggesting changing the White Balance.  That, and maybe setting exposure to -1, is a great way to really change the feeling of a scene on a cloudy day.

Answer (score 5):

Photography is not just about the beautiful things in life although many people only thought of shooting good-looking things.

You can go shoot things that people don't.

I am sure you have seen a photo of a landmark, in perfect weather, blue sky and white cloud.

Have you seen the same landmark shot during a thunderstorm?

You can shoot it during rain, storm, snow, fog etc.

Show the unseen side of the same scene.

Answer (score 2):

Shoot up at buildings, landmarks, people using the cloudy sky as a dramatic background.

For subjects that are near enough, a touch of flash can make the sky darker and more dramatic.

(i.e. it makes the subject brighter, you expose for the subject, so the sky is darker in the final image).

Answer (score 1):

I've always been fond of shots of primary color umbrellas agains the sea of darker monotone umbrellas. Try a little underexposure to saturate the colors. Another favorite is the shot of a woman's legs and high heels running thru puddles. Shiny patent leather against wet streets looks great - use the reflections of street lights, traffic lights and store signs  to add some color. Happy Shooting! And btw - if you're shooting in the rain get a 1-gallon zip-lock bag to protect your camera. ou can cut a hole out for the lens and eyepiece.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your composition to incorporate the mood. Take the macro of a rain drop, kid dancing in the rain, people running from the rain.. catch their emotions. Here's a [compilation](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/rainy-day-image?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20DigitalPhotographySchool%20%28Digital%20Photography%20School%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) from digital-photography-school that might get your creative juices flowing.